# passing identifier and type to macro

Tags: c, macros, identifier

I'm trying to pass an identifier and a type to a macro that should declare the variable

```
#define DECLARE_PARAM(TYPE, PARAM) \
  TYPE PARAM; \
  gboolean __exist_##PARAM = FALSE

...

DECLARE_PARAM(char[100], title);
```

but I'm getting compilation errors :

```
expected identifier or '(' before '[' token
   DECLARE_PARAM(char[100], title);
                     ^
```

**EDIT**

It works with simple types such char or int, is there a way I can pass an array type?

**CONTEXT**

I'm actually trying to make a variadic function that takes a string of parameters name separated by spaces `"title color other"` and then their values so it would be called like this :

```
create_window("color title", "blue", "My window");
```

so the function would give **default values** to the none specified argument.

I wrote this as a test, but now I need to put this boilerplate code into a macro like this
for example :

```
DEFAULT_PARAM(title, char[100], "My window");
```

here is the test I wrote

```
#define DECLARE_PARAM(TYPE, PARAM) \
  TYPE PARAM; \
  gboolean __exist_##PARAM = FALSE

GtkWidget *fenetre_creer(char *keys, ...)
{
  va_list args;

  DECLARE_PARAM(char[100], titre);
  DECLARE_PARAM(char[100], icon);
  DECLARE_PARAM(int, padding);

  GList *argList = read_args(keys);
  int nombreArguments = g_list_length(argList);

  va_start(args, nombreArguments);

  GList *iterator = argList;
  while(iterator)
    {
      char *argument = iterator->data;
      if(strcmp(argument, "titre"))
        {
          strcpy(titre, va_arg(args, char*));
          _titre_param = TRUE;
        }
      else if(strcmp(argument, "icon"))
        {
          strcpy(icon, va_arg(args, char*));
          _icon_param = TRUE;
        }
      else if (strcmp(argument, "padding"))
        {
          padding = va_arg(args, int);
          _padding_param = TRUE;
        }
      iterator = iterator->next;
    }
  var_end();

  if(!__exist_titre)
    strcpy(titre, "Titre de la fenetre");
  if(!__exist_padding)
    padding = 10;
  if(!__exist_icon)
    strcpy(icon, "");

  printf("titre : %s\n", titre);
  printf("padding : %d\n", padding);
  printf("icon : %s\n", icon);

}
```

Comment: What compilation errors?

Comment: It's a bit of a guessing game. Please provide more context.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `char titre[100]`, not `char[100]` titre? I don't think this is about your macro, it's just an incorrect variable declaration.

Comment: good point, @computerfreaker ... the `char[100]` form would be legal C++, but I'm not convinced it would work in C. It could be made to work by using typedef to give that type a name, I suppose...

Comment: Since the rewrite for an array is not trivial, you can't do it quite like that.  However, given `typedef char CharArray100[100];`, you could use `DECLARE_PARAM(CharArray100, title);`.  But the fact that you run into such errors is an indication that what you're trying to do is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Also, note that names starting with double underscore `__` are reserved for the implementation (for any purpose).  You are playing with fire using them — and will have no-one but yourself to blame if you subsequently get burned.  Similarly, names starting with underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation; in fact, you'd do well to assume that identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved and that you should not use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, `char[100] foo` is legal Java but not legal C or C++, at least in the dialects I've used.

I'm not guaranteeing it, but you could try:

```
typedef char Char100[100];
DECLARE_PARAM(Char100, titre);
```

I suspect that would work. ***HOWEVER*, using macros to add syntax to the language is *almost always a bad idea.*** You really aren't saving yourself that much work, and you're creating a not-quite-C program which will be harder for other C programmers to work with. Don't do it for trivial things like this, and if you must do it **document it to death**.

Especially since you can say the same thing more clearly as

```
typedef char Char100[100];
Char100 titre;
```

**RESPONDING TO EDIT FOR "CONTEXT":**

Default parameters is a very different question. For that, define wrapper functions which take a subset of the arguments and fill in the missing values before calling the general version. Or define the function to recognize a reserved value (null, or -1, or something else that won't otherwise occur) as a request to use the default value for that parameter. Much cleaner than trying to warp the syntax of the language.

Comment: I know that what I'm doing is not good :D. I just need to have default parameters in C if it's possible.

Comment: The only difference is the additional `bool __exist_titre = false;` definition too.  But your answer substantially echoes my comment; I assume you were writing yours when I posted mine.

Comment: @YoussefBouhjira: if you want features from C++, use C++.  It's easier than fighting C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wish I could :( . C is a requirement

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yep; simultaneous thoughts.

Comment: It's not legal C++, either. `char[100]` is a type-specifier followed by an abstract-declarator in either language, and abstract-declarators don't work in declarations. Also, macro shortcuts are not "almost always a bad idea"; using macros to get declarations is particularly commonplace. Yes, this kind of practice can save a lot of work.

Comment: We agree that we disagree, @Potatoswatter. It may be commonplace in your community of practice; it's been rare in what I've seen and I have never seen a usage that I thought was actually an improvement. Admittedly I haven't worked intensively in C for a decade, and the language has evolved somewhat since then, but I would fail this example if asked to code-review it and I don't think I'm alone in that.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't see his use case. Yes, this kind of thing needs to be justified a bit better than we see here.